# На чем сделать систему автополива и открытия/закрытия теплицы?

Tags: arduino, автоматизация, умный-дом

В общем-то, задача, которая стоит передо мной, описана в заголовке, сейчас опишу, как  вижу процесс:
 1. Компьютер - на данный момент обычный, в идеале Arduino.
 2. Электроклапан (для отключения/включения подачи воды).
 3. Электропривод стекла (для открывания форточек теплицы), думаю взять простой автомобильный.
 4. Аккумулятор - тут вообще не знаю, что взять под это дело, не знаю, подойдет ли автомобильный.
 5. Как-то воткнуть в это дело gsm модуль (3g модем как вариант).

Ну вот, в общем-то и все, то есть схема работы отправили смс с одним кодом, вода полилась, с другим остановилась и т.д. Потом можно будет датчики температуры воткнуть и тому подобные приколюхи! Но вот хотелось бы получить инфу от опытных людей, как все это организовать.   Заранее спасибо!

Comment: имхо, ардуино - баловство. если умный дом не заканчивается на теплице, то систему стоит строить на чем-то более серьезном.  
если проект доведете до завершения, было бы интересно послушать что и как у вас получилось.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, просто его посреди огорода легче было бы расположить и укрыть от влаги и жары, чем обычный компьютер.

Comment: @Артур Пантелеев, ну есть же беспроводные системы, которые и укрывать не пришлось бы. В любом случае та или иная реализация заслуживает внимания. Про ардуино это я со своей колокольни - имхо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raspberry PI2 и Arduino +gsm модуль + powerRalayPad (если ток большой).

По простому- микрокомпьютер Rasperry Pi2 (он с ардуиной вяжется, есть много всяких примеров в открытом доступе), ваша ардуино (достаточно просто в части написания кода под нее). gsm модуль для ардуины тоже есть, и есть примеры работы с ним и работы по командам принятым. PowerRelyaPad не что иное как управление силывами реле. Если меня не подводит память, то это на случай работы с 220в. Допускаю что мои познания в части плат управления выходами несколько устарели, но помнится мне есть плата управления выходами т.е. по сути подача питания на ваши подъемники.

И еще сразу решите задачу актуации положения окна т.к. вероятность того что сломается ЭСП существует. Посмотрите в сторону герконов или чего-то подобного сигнализациям на окна.

Почему пока что лучше использовать ардуино - простота в написании и доступность как примеров, так и компонентов. То, что у вас получится в итоге будет прототипом, на основе которого вы сможете исполнить реализацию на более правильных, с точки зрения отказоустойчивости, компонентов.

Answer (score 0):

Предвижу проблемы с *GSM*-модулем. Надёжность работы *GSM*-модуля целиком во власти оператора сотовой связи. Поэтому я бы делал так. Подключился к мобильному интернету через роутер. А уже к роутеру подключил *Arduino* через *WiFi*-шилд. На *Arduine* крутится *Web*-клиент, который раз в 5 минут связывается с сервером, передавая данные с датчика влажности (ведь если влажность высокая, то полив не требуется). А уже сервер отвечает, поливать или нет. Это чтобы можно было на сервере задать параметры полива через удобный веб-интерфейс.

Answer (score 0):

ардуино+реле шилд+аналоговый измеритель влаги + датчик света и температуры 2 шт
суть уйти от вмешательства человека (GSM) 
логика 
замеряем температуру внутри
выше открываем окна ниже закрываем 
если ночь и температура за окном ниже и в парнике тоже ниже, то не открываем ждем утра
влага - принцип сухо льем влажно не льем

Comment: да и про герконы тоже не помешают